# Backwards animation not working properly in Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a simple Javascript game which consists in a square expanding, while the player have to hit "A" to make it smaller. The goal is to make the square disappear and not to let the square engulf the whole screen.

But I'm experiencing three issues:
- When I hit A, the square stops expanding and starts getting smaller, but it never stops. It should only work for a about a second and then expand again.
- The pause button (enter) doesn't always work the way it should. I feel like it waits for the animation stop, but I don't want it to work like this.
- The square doesn't expand from the center.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/game.css"></link>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/game.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="game">
            <div id="game" style="position:absolute;"><img id="player" class="square"></img></div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript:

```
//set update interval
setInterval(update, 10);
var isPlaying = false;

$(document).ready(function() {

});



function playerInput() {
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if ( event.which == 65 ) {
            if (isPlaying == true) {
                $("#player").animate({height: '-=10', width: '-=10'}, 1);
            }
        } else if (event.which == 13) {
            isPlaying = !isPlaying;
        }
    });
}


function update() {
    playerInput();
    if (isPlaying == true) {
        $("#player").animate({height: '+=10', width: '+=10'}, 1);
    }
}
```

The CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
}

.game {
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: black;

}

.square {
    background-image: url("../images/square.png");
    margin: 375px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Can you put it in a fiddle

Comment: I tried to put the image in the fiddle, but it's not working.

Comment: you can not upload images. You need to grab them from a site or some sort of host! I think you can do drop box or something like that!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/menzoni/2yqv8pka/

Comment: The image works now, but nothing all the rest doesn't. I've never used a fiddle before. I don't need to upload the jquery file too, right?

Comment: No you don't. Bro is really easy ... read a little bit. Is it already there, there is a dropdown on which you select the jQuery version you want.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty dumb. Just fixed it.

Comment: @CarlosMenzoni: Take a look at **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/ut8vd5b8/)** that I just created using **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)**.